# Remove address from instruction disassembled via dbgeng's DisassembleWide()

Tags: debugging, winapi, windbg, dbgeng

I am disassembling instructions by passing their offset to `DisassembleWide()` function while writing an extension for Windbg. However, with the disassembled instruction, it adds the address of the instruction + hex opcode for that instruction.

I was able to remove the opcode by specifying `DEBUG_ASMOPT_NO_CODE_BYTES` flag in `SetAssemblyOptions()`. However I can't seem to get rid of the instruction offset. Neither `DEBUG_ASMOPT_DEFAULT | DEBUG_ASMOPT_NO_CODE_BYTES`, nor `(DEBUG_ASMOPT_DEFAULT | DEBUG_ASMOPT_NO_CODE_BYTES) & ~DEBUG_ASMOPT_VERBOSE` seem to work.

Am I missing something? Is there a way I can cleanly remove the offset from the instruction, or will I have to do it the manual way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no Address will always be printed you have to parse it out yourself 
if you are on a windbg session you can achieve this with .shell and awk

```
0:000> .asm no_code_bytes
Assembly options: no_code_bytes
0:000> .shell -ci "u @eip l4" awk "{$1=\"\";print $0}"

 int 3
 ret
 mov edi,edi

 int 3
.shell: Process exited
```